# Android Hide Part of a View

Tags: android, forms, view, hide, shapes

I'm looking for a solution to hide a part of a View (not only drawable View but every kind of view like an WebView, Video, ImageView, Button etc..).
I need to display by example a video with round or polygonal form and to do that I would like to create a polygonal Path and hide pixel which are outside this path.

Someone knows if it's possible on Android?

I have already find a solution for iOS like that:

```
UIBezierPath *Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[Path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0)];
[Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
[Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
[Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
[Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
[Path closePath];

CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
mask.frame = view.bounds;
mask.path = Path.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = mask;
```

Thank you for your help